# how to display data comming from pipe on GUI form in C #

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, pipe, operation

I have made a small server and client application connected via named pipe. I am able to communicate between them in console application. Now i want that data to be displayed in text box on form.

I am not able to display, once i assign the data it gets assigned but text box is not showing the new up dated value.

Can any one help me to resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Could you show us some code ? It would probably help.

Taking a wild guess based on the information you have already provided, perhaps you are continously polling for data on the GUI thread ? That would effectively block the thread, so that the GUI never gets around to redrawing the text box.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following code after you set the new value for the textbox :

```
   textBox1.AppendText(yourData); // let's say, you add your data here
   textBox1.Update();
   Application.DoEvents();
```